# DNN site stop working

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have a dnn installation with 3 portals. Everything was fine for couple months.

Sites stopped working completely and all I have is 2 error messages in the logs.

> [Thread:61][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
>      at System.Threading.Thread.SleepInternal(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
>      at System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling.Scheduler.CoreScheduler.RunEventSchedule(EventName eventName)
>
> [Thread:61][FATAL] DotNetNuke.Web.Common.Internal.DotNetNukeHttpApplication - System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.

So the error messages dont mean anything. Any ideas?

Comment: There's not much in the stack trace for us to help you with, I recommend asking this on the DNN forums instead.

Comment: The error messages do mean something. It means your web request is taking too long, so the server is killing it by aborting the thread. So now you know that some part of the application is too slow, and you could potentially profile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotNetNuke.Services.**Scheduling.Scheduler**

This was the clue for me, I disabled all the scheduled task from database and site start working again. One of the task were taking so long and causing timeout.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Has helped me twice trying to upgrade from 7.4.2 too 9.1.1, thank you!